# Codeigniter controller created when image not found

Tags: php, codeigniter, httprequest

I have a problem in CodeIgniter, and that is that when an image is not found on the server, the instance of a controller is created (besides the one that called the view).

I know all this can sound confusing, so this is the code to observe what I'm saying. I did this changes to a clean 2.1.0 CI version:

Add a controller to override the 404 error page, I added this one:

```
// add application/controllers/Errors.php 
Class Errors extends CI_Controller {

    public function error_404() {
        echo 'error';
    }
}
// change routes.php
$route['404_override'] = 'Errors/error_404';
```

Use a controller that isn’t the default one with an unexisting image, I used this:

```
// add application/controllers/Foo.php 
Class Foo extends CI_Controller {

    public function index() {
        echo '<img src="doesntexist.png" />';
    }

}
```

I couldn’t figure out another way of debugging it, so I created a log to write the events on CodeIgniter.php:

```
// add on CodeIgniter.php line 356
$path = 'log.txt'; //Place log where you can find it
$file = fopen($path, 'a');
fwrite($file, "Calling method {$class}/{$method} with request {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}\r\n");
fclose($file);
```

With this, the log that generates visiting the index function is the following:

```
Calling method Foo/index with request /test/index.php/Foo
Calling method Errors/error_404 with request /test/index.php/doesntexist.png
```

Which is the problem I have, an instance of the Error class is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
that is that when an image is not found on the server, the instance of a controller is created
```

Not really. What I believe is happening is that, since you're using a relative path for the image (and calling it directly inside a controller, which is wrong because you're ouputting something before headers), your browser attach the image directly to the CI url, thus making this request to the server:

```
index.php/doesntexist.png
```

Which is (correctly) interpreted by CI as a request to a controller, which doesn't exists, and therefore it issues the error class.

You could do, in your actual code (I'd put the images in a view, though):

```
echo '<img src="/doesntexist.png" />'
```

using an absoluth path, or using the base_url() method from the url helper:

```
echo '<img src="'.base_url().'doesntexist.png" />
```

This should tell the server to fetch the right request (`/test/doesntexist.png`) and won't trigger that error.